# It's not possible to rearrange the communities list on a touch screen

Tags: bug, responsive-design, communities-list

On Chrome 115.0.5790.138 or Firefox beta (116.0b8) for Android, once you add a community to the "Your Communities" list in the editing view, it's not possible to reorder the sites.

- Single-finger dragging scrolls the drop-down box
- Two-finger dragging scrolls the page
- Long-pressing the dotted bar does nothing
- Long-pressing the site name opens the browser's context menu for the link

This is also reproducible on Microsoft Edge on Windows, using a touchscreen PC.

[image]

Comment: Does it work in Chrome? P.S. I'm lazy to check...

Comment: Not possible on Chrome either. I don't have an iOS device handy with my personal accounts signed in to check there

Comment: Pretty sure it's not going to work with any touchscreen. PS: Tested on iOS Chrome.